# Is the word Idiota considered masculine, or feminine, or does it depend on the subject?

Tags: género

Is the word *Idiota* considered masculine, or feminine, or does it depend on the subject? For example, would I say "él es *un* idiota," "él es *una* idiota," or "él es *un* idiota y ella es *una* idiota?"

Comment: Note: its really hard for me to find what tags to use since I don't know them all and don't know all of the Spanish words for what they potentially could be, so someone more knowledgeable should update them.

Comment: You might have added uso-de-palabras I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Your last option is the correct one: it depends on the article only, as "idiota" is valid both for male and female.

This is common to many words enging in "a", like idiota, astronauta, asceta...